# HTML5 not playing videos on shared folder

Tags: html, video

My company has a shared folder with videos to play on a web page.
I can play the video on any browser if I copy it to my site public folder, but how can I just link it to the shared folder?

Something like this:

```
    <video id="vid" width="100%" height="100%" controls>
        <source src="\\sharedfolder\big_buck_bunny.mp4" />
    </video>
```

if I paste it on firefox it plays, transforming the address to file://///sharedfolder/big_buck_bunny.mp4
But even if I put this in the source tag it wont work.

Using PHP5.5, Apache 2.4, Laravel 4.2 Framework on Windows

Comment: is the shared folder outward facing?  ALSO:  Why not symlink to it?

Comment: what do you mean with symlink. Not familiarized with it

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link    you can say something like:  `ln -s big_buck_bunny.mp4 path/to/sharedfolder/big_buck_bunny.mp4`

Comment: I'm working on windows. Note: This function does not work on Windows platforms. I updated my OP.

Comment: you would need: `mklink` instead then.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the `mklink` command, you will be able to link a file from 1 directory to another.  If you are working with Linux, you would need something like:

```
ln -s big_buck_bunny.mp4 path/to/sharedfolder/big_buck_bunny.mp4
```

but there is info in `mklink --help` which will tell you what to do.

Remember if you are going to deploy systems, this might cause issues until your deployment script is corrected for the source of that file. :)